# Regex negative lookbehind max "length"

Tags: regex

**It actually does work.**

I am trying to use Regex to match strings with one character surrounded by single quotes `'` where both quotes cannot be preceded by a backslash `\`.

This is my Regex:

`(?<!\\)'(.{1})(?<!\\)'`

It uses negative lookbehind to ensure that the quotes are not preceded by a backslash.

So far, it works great, but I've run into a certain problem:

From `'H'ello world!` it matches `'H'`, and from `\'H'ello world` it doen't match `'H'` because the `'H'` is preceded by `\`.

The problem I run into is that if I have this string:

`'I' have \'r'eally bad 'e'xamples`

it will match `'I'` because it is not preceded by `\`, it won't match `\'r'` because it is preceded by `\`, but it **won't** match `'e'` because it is not **directly** preceded by `\` but there is an occurrence of `\` before that (before `'r'`).

So my question is, is there any way to specify a "maximum distance" that the negative lookbehind should look for the `\`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It matches `'e'` here: https://regex101.com/r/pS6uT3/1

Comment: `but it won't match 'e' because it is not directly preceded by \ but there is an occurrence of \ before that (before 'r')` unclear for me.

Comment: If you don't have a quantified RE after the negative lookbehind, it only looks immediately behind, there's no distance.

Comment: @Barmar Could it be because I am using .NET that the results are different? (Your link uses PHP)

Comment: If you're using PCRE it should be the same.

Comment: I don't know .NET -- make sure you're using a function that finds all matches, not just the first one.

Comment: @Barmar I was using a program called Expresso to test the Regex and it didn't work but I put it into my actual program and it works. Thanks for your help, and sorry for kinda wasting your time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your look behind is not variable length; it has length exactly 1, because it has only one character.

Secondly, you only need *one* look behind; the second one is not needed if the dot doesn't match a backslash.

Your regex can be simplified to:

```
(?<!\\)'[^\\]'
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I thought the look behind looked behind in the WHOLE string, not just directly behind the character.